# How do I change what "cmake -E cmake_link_script" emits?

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, mingw-w64

I have a directory in my build that looks like this:

```
/home/ubuntu/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec614603832.dir:
...                                                                             
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  140 May  2 19:45 link.txt                           
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  720 May  2 19:45 testCCompiler.c.obj
```

I'm trying to figure out how `link.txt` gets generated.  It looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc \                               
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec614603832.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj \
  -o cmTryCompileExec614603832 -rdynamic
```

and I would like to get rid of the `-rdynamic`, since with it, linking fails, and with it, the linking step succeeds.

Of course I tried other settings up at the level of command line options to `cmake`, and in `CMakeLists.txt`, but I haven't figured out the magic incantation that will make `-rdynamic` go away.

If it matters, I'm trying to build on an Amazon Ubuntu instance, cross compiling to `mingw64`, since building on Windows itself has been very problematic.

Comment: Part of which `cmake`'s test this comipliation? Do you use `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` for your cross compilation? What did you write in your toolchain file?

Comment: No, I have not used `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`.  I'm fairly new to CMake.  The software builds fine on GNU/Linux and Mac OS X.  Unfortunately, I need to build it for Windows, and use MinGW64.  I'll have to lookup how to use `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`, since I don't know what value I'd give that symbol.

Comment: you can read about cross compilation here: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling#Setting_up_the_system_and_toolchain Cross compilation different from ordinary compilation, because of `cmake` can not guess about suitable compiler flags and so on stuff, in you case it thinks that `-rdynamic` should work

Comment: Thanks.  I'll check that out.